# Does the xamarin mono android runtime support windows forms?

Tags: android, winforms, mono

My game engine currently use windows form as the UI, but I know mono supports windows forms as well. So I'm wondering if the mono android runtime support windows form too?

Comment: No, `Xamarin.Forms` or native Android UI via `Xamarin.Android`

Comment: Ok, then I'll try make the port by myself, thanks.